# Generate excel from html

Tags: html, excel

I am trying to generate excel file and my data is in the form of HTML string. I have an HTML table with few columns and rows. I am generating one huge HTML table with n rows and n column in java and saving that string into a flat file and naming that file as mydata.html or mydata.xls. When this file is opened using Microsoft Excel, it shows the table in the column-wise format. The document is rendered perfectly fine. This is the simplest way to generate the file in excel.

Please find attached the sample HTML file. Save this file as mydata.html or mydata.xls and open it using Microsoft excel. If saved as .xls, click yes in the excel dialog box at the time of opening.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<style>
table {
    font-family: arial, sans-serif;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border: 1px solid #dddddd;
    width: 75%;
    valign:top;
}

td, th {
    border: 1px solid #dddddd;
    text-align: left;
    padding: 8px;
    valign:top;
    width: 25%;
}

tr:nth-child(even) {
    background-color: #dddddd;
    border: 1px solid #dddddd;valign:top;
}
</style>
<body>

<table>
  <tr>
    <th valign="top">Column 1</th>
    <th valign="top">Column 2 </th>
    <th valign="top">Column 3 </th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td valign="top">Row 1  Column 1</td>
    <td valign="top">
     <p>
     <b>Paragraph 1 </b>. This is a large text which spills over multiple lines.Java is at the heart of our digital lifestyle. It's the platform for launching careers, exploring human-to-digital interfaces, architecting the world's best applications, and unlocking innovation everywhere from garages to global organizations. When it comes to building computer programming skills, learning Java will take you way beyond the games of your childhood. Knowing Java will be a clear advantage in your future career. Learning Java can be a skill for a career, or a skill for fun or both. Students of all ages have built amazing things, from hobby projects to world-changing initiatives. Oracle Academy Workshops are designed to make first experiences with computing fun and engaging, while still leveraging best academic curriculum practices like project-based learning and offering educators methods for assessment. Oracle Academy Workshops are best used by educators in one of three ways: to introduce students, including students as young as late primary school ages, to computer science in a fun and engaging way;
  to incorporate exposure to computer science into the teaching of other academic disciplines; and
  to offer a limited introduction to computer science to students via extra-curricular programs and/or workshop experiences.

  </p>
  <p><b>Paragraph 2 </b> --> Like our Getting Started with Java Using Alice Workshop, this freely available course is designed for teachers, students and individuals with little or no programming experience and teaches basic Java programming concepts through developing 3-D animations in Alice 3.1. Alice is a free, educational, introductory Java development environment created at Carnegie Mellon University. While it is suitable for all beginning learners, it can be especially engaging for girls. Learners will have fun creating animated stories and games using objects and characters from a rich gallery of 3-D models.
  </p>
  <p><b>Paragraph 3  </b> Oracle Academy Workshops are also available to Individual and Institutional members in Workshop in a Box formats to facilitate the delivery of introductory computer science workshops by parents, volunteers, computer club sponsors and educators who may not specialize in teaching computer science</p>
 </td>
    <td valign="top">
     <p>
     <b>Paragraph 1 </b>.
      When you learn Java, youre learning more than just a language. Because Java is a technology platform with many interconnected capabilities that can give cutting-edge, in-demand job skills. In fact, Java tops Inc.coms list of the ten most popular programming languages. Java can take you where you want to go. Learn how to create games, simulations and other graphical programs using basic Java programming via free educational Java development environments from Carnegie Mellon University (Alice) and the University of Kent (Greenfoot). No prior programming or computer science experience is required.
     </p>
     <p>
     <b>Paragraph 2 </b>.
     Oracle Academy self-study courses are designed to provide a self-paced learning experience for teachers, students and individuals.
     </p>
     <p><b>Paragraph 3 </b>Oracle Academy Workshop in a Box are designed to facilitate the delivery of introductory computer science workshops by parents, volunteers, computer club sponsors and educators who may not specialize in teaching computer science.
      </p>
    </td>
  </tr>

</table>

</body>
</html>
```

However, I am facing one major problem. Any paragraph (P tag) or the line break(using 
 tag) causes the adjacent cells to jump to the next row. Please open the attached HTML file using excel. The column 2 and column 3 have 3 paragraph in them. Please observe the alignment of paragraph 2  of column 3. Paragraph 2 of column 3 doesn't start right after paragraph 1, it rather starts in same line as paragraph 2 of column 2. There is a lot of blank spaces above the paragraph 2 of column 3. I want the paragraph 2 should start right after the paragraph 1.  If the html file is opened in browser, the alignment of paragraph is perfect.

I want the paragraph 2 should start right after the paragraph 1. Please find attached the image file.
[image]

Comment: Yes, I need to preserve the formatting. The process is, there is a html editor as part of the application for rich text input. It so happening that the users are either typing the content in to this editor or they copy paste the contents from word. So there is a mix and max of html as well as word formats. Later they try to generate the excel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use the line break tag `<br>` instead of the paragraph tag `<p>`, just add the style .... `style="mso-data-placement:same-cell;"` .. here is your example

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<style>
table {
    font-family: arial, sans-serif;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border: 1px solid #dddddd;
    width: 75%;
    valign:top;
}

td, th {
    border: 1px solid #dddddd;
    text-align: left;
    padding: 8px;
    valign:top;
    width: 25%;
}

tr:nth-child(even) {
    background-color: #dddddd;
    border: 1px solid #dddddd;valign:top;
}
</style>
<body>

<table>
  <tr>
    <th valign="top">Column 1</th>
    <th valign="top">Column 2 </th>
    <th valign="top">Column 3 </th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td valign="top">Row 1  Column 1</td>
    <td valign="top">
     
     <b>Paragraph 1 </b>. This is a large text which spills over multiple lines.Java is at the heart of our digital lifestyle. It's the platform for launching careers, exploring human-to-digital interfaces, architecting the world's best applications, and unlocking innovation everywhere from garages to global organizations. When it comes to building computer programming skills, learning Java will take you way beyond the games of your childhood. Knowing Java will be a clear advantage in your future career. Learning Java can be a skill for a career, or a skill for fun or both. Students of all ages have built amazing things, from hobby projects to world-changing initiatives. Oracle Academy Workshops are designed to make first experiences with computing fun and engaging, while still leveraging best academic curriculum practices like project-based learning and offering educators methods for assessment. Oracle Academy Workshops are best used by educators in one of three ways: to introduce students, including students as young as late primary school ages, to computer science in a fun and engaging way;
  to incorporate exposure to computer science into the teaching of other academic disciplines; and
  to offer a limited introduction to computer science to students via extra-curricular programs and/or workshop experiences.

  <br style="mso-data-placement:same-cell;" />
  
  <b>Paragraph 2 </b> --> Like our Getting Started with Java Using Alice Workshop, this freely available course is designed for teachers, students and individuals with little or no programming experience and teaches basic Java programming concepts through developing 3-D animations in Alice 3.1. Alice is a free, educational, introductory Java development environment created at Carnegie Mellon University. While it is suitable for all beginning learners, it can be especially engaging for girls. Learners will have fun creating animated stories and games using objects and characters from a rich gallery of 3-D models.
  
  <br style="mso-data-placement:same-cell;" />
  
  <b>Paragraph 3  </b> Oracle Academy Workshops are also available to Individual and Institutional members in Workshop in a Box formats to facilitate the delivery of introductory computer science workshops by parents, volunteers, computer club sponsors and educators who may not specialize in teaching computer science 
  
  <br style="mso-data-placement:same-cell;" />
 
 </td>
    <td valign="top">
     
     <b>Paragraph 1 </b>.
      When you learn Java, youre learning more than just a language. Because Java is a technology platform with many interconnected capabilities that can give cutting-edge, in-demand job skills. In fact, Java tops Inc.coms list of the ten most popular programming languages. Java can take you where you want to go. Learn how to create games, simulations and other graphical programs using basic Java programming via free educational Java development environments from Carnegie Mellon University (Alice) and the University of Kent (Greenfoot). No prior programming or computer science experience is required.
     <br style="mso-data-placement:same-cell;" />
  
     
     <b>Paragraph 2 </b>.
     Oracle Academy self-study courses are designed to provide a self-paced learning experience for teachers, students and individuals.
     <br style="mso-data-placement:same-cell;" />
  
     <b>Paragraph 3 </b>Oracle Academy Workshop in a Box are designed to facilitate the delivery of introductory computer science workshops by parents, volunteers, computer club sponsors and educators who may not specialize in teaching computer science.
     <br style="mso-data-placement:same-cell;" />
    </td>
  </tr>

</table>

</body>
</html>
```

And here's the result  [CLICK FOR THE RESULT IN EXCEL](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CcYjr.jpg)

Comment: Thanks a lot and it really worked like a charm. I need to see how to incorporate this as the html data is inputted by the end user and I really have no flexibility in manipulating the contents. But thanks again for the timely help.

Comment: you are welcome, you can still publish what you need in the site, there are competent people who can help you !